# Differentiability of $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow C$ where $C$ is a finite set

Tags: real-analysis

I'm having a confusion with the definition of differentiable: is it true that we only define 'differentiable' for functions which have as domain and co-domain (a subset of) the real numbers? I.e., can I say the following:

> Let $f$ be a fuction $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow C$ where $C$ is some finite set with $|C| > 1$ and $\forall c \in C \ \exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(x) = c$. Such a mapping $f$ can not be differentiable.

Or how would you express the notion that it is not possible to think of differentiable when talking about such functions?

Comment: Such a map could be differentiable at some points of $\mathbb R$ and not others.  So the useful notion would not be "the function is differentiable" but "the function is differentiable at a point".

Comment: @GEdgar Okay. But I can say "$f$ is not continuous everywhere => $f$ is not differentiable everywhere", right?

Comment: Differentiability at a point implies continuity at that point, so discontinuity at a point implies nondifferentiability at that point (i.e., $(D\implies C)\iff(\lnot C\implies \lnot D)$)

Comment: I assume that $C\subset\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C$ is finite, there are some $c_{1},\dots, c_{n} \in \mathbb{R}$ (here $\mathbb{R}$ can be replaced with a metric space in general) such that $C = \{ c_{1}, \dots, c_{n} \}$. Then $d := \min_{1 \leq i \neq j \leq n} |c_{i}-c_{j}| > 0$. Now for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$, say $\varepsilon := d/2$, such that for every $\delta > 0$ and every $x' \neq x$ we have $|f(x')-f(x)| = |c_{i}-c_{j}| \geq d > \varepsilon$ for some $1 \leq i \neq j \leq n$. So $f$ is not continuous and hence not differentiable.

Note that $|f(x) - f(x')| = \frac{|f(x)-f(x')|}{|x-x'|}\cdot |x-x'|$ for all $x \neq x'$; so differentiablity implies continuity.

Comment: Thanks, that feels very intuitive

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is differentiable it is continuous, therefore it maps the connected set $\Bbb R$ to another connected set. Since $|C|>1$, the image is disconnected a contradiction to the assumption of continuity. If you are not familiar with the term "connected" yet, just use the intermediate value theorem. Choose $x,y\in C$ so that $x<y$ and there is no $z\in C$ such that $x<z<y$, i.e. they are adjacent. Then since $f$ does not take on every value between $x$ and $y$ it does not satisfy the intermediate value theorem, in particular it is not continuous.